# Filtering excel data with pandas

Tags: python, excel

I am trying to read an excel file and filter data in excel file. For example

[image: excel data]

I want to read this in Python. Moreover, I want to filter data directly taken from excel in Python. For example, I want to define ranges for apples and categorize them like "best" and "worst". Lets say, apples which are below 3 are "worst" and above 5 are "best".

Does anyone have any idea how can I do that?

Comment: welcome to SO, any tries yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you need:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(filename) #read file
df = pd.DataFrame({'Apples':np.random.randint(0,10,size=10)}) #for demo
df['Apples_cat'] = (pd.cut(df['Apples'],bins=[-np.inf,2,5,np.inf],labels=['worst','ok','best']))
print(df)
```

Output: (since df is random generate in the demo, the output would be a bit diff)

```
   Apples Apples_cat
0       2      worst
1       2      worst
2       5         ok
3       2      worst
4       1      worst
5       5         ok
6       5         ok
7       6       best
8       4         ok
9       2      worst
```

Comment: When I run the code this error occurs: NameError: name 'np' is not defined

Comment: @OykuAtes, added the line `import numpy as np` to the code example

Comment: Thank you for your response @AlexFung, it worked for simple excel file. But when I tried to run it for an other excel file like [https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLoFC.png]  it gives KeyError: 'apples'

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_excel ('fruits.xls')

data['apple_category'] = "medium"

data.loc[data['Apples'] < 3, 'apple_category'] = "worst"
data.loc[data['Apples'] > 5, 'apple_category'] = "best"
```